# Can't update TextView from another activity

Tags: java, android, textview

I have an activity with a TextView that needs to be updated from a second activity.
I can pass the Text view data to the 2nd activity ok, but when I try to update that TextView
within the 2nd activity it crashes. My code:

1st Activity (where the TextView is defined in my xml):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(1stactivity.this, 2ndactivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("homescore_value", ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.score_home)).getText());
startActivity(intent);

// code snippet
```

Then in my 2nd activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
hometext = bundle.getString("homescore_value"); // this works and displays the correct String from 1st activity,
```

but it crashes when I try to pull in as a `TextView`:

```
// other code snipped
int homescore = 0;
String Home_nickname = "HOME ";

TextView homestext = (TextView) bundle.get("homescore_value");
hometext.setText(Home_nickname +": "+homescore   );
```

Please help.

Comment: Please paste the LogCat exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to cast `String` to `TextView`. The code that crashes is equivalent of:

```
String text = bundle.get("homescore_value"); //this is ok
TextView textView = (TextView)text; //this is bad
```

You should do instead:

```
String text = bundle.get("homescore_value");
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
textView.setText(text);
```

Comment: the 3rd line causes a crash: textView.setText(text);

Comment: You need to change `R.id.yourTextViewId` to correct id of your text view in activity layout.

Comment: I have changed R.id.yourTextViewId to match what I have in my 1st activities layout. but Im using this in my 2nd activity, how does it recognize it, since the 2nd activity has a totally different layout? thx

Comment: In your second layout (layout for second activity) you should include TextView with `android:id="@+id/youtTextViewId` in any place you like.

Comment: I actually don't need to update a TextView within the 2nd activity, that activity just calculates a value, that I store in shared preferences. my goal was to try and refresh the textview in the 1st activity with that value once the 2nd activity finishes.

Comment: You can't update `TextView` from first activity from you second activity (you can, but should not). Instead you `startActivityForResult` and return result to your first activity. You first activity will parse result in its `onActivityResult` function. For an example see: http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#returningaresult

Comment: that example did it! using startActivityForResult and the Listener

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to get a String as a TextView (you are setting a String in the intent from the first Activity).

Answer (score 0):

This line here:

```
intent.putExtra("homescore_value", ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.score_home)).getText());
```

is attaching a String along with the intent, not a TextView.

You must inflate a new TextView within the 2nd activity, by either declaring it in the layout.xml, or programmatically placing it within the layout.

Comment: String text = (String) bundle.get("homescore_value");
         TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score_home);
        // textView.setText(text); -- > crashes when I use this line

Comment: how do inflate the TextView defined in 1st activity in the 2nd activity? I thought that was the reason for using the putExtra. so that the 2nd activity recognizes what that TextView is? I guess I am missing something here. thx for your help.

Comment: Think of the `TextView` as a placeholder for text and not the actual text.
With an intent you will notice you can't actually send a textView as it is not a primitive data type or implementing `Parcelable`.
So basically when you call `textView.getText()` your getting the string that was in it, and sending that over the intent. So `TextView` is just a bucket/placeholder to put your string in.
You will need to set up another `TextView` so that the second layout knows where to put it.
Hope that helps you some :)

Comment: ok yes I see what you mean, but my goal is when the 2nd activity closes (using the finish():) command, my 1st activity will resume, and thats where I need the text updated. somehow i need it refreshed automatically. the textview data comes from a stored shared preference, so that is not an issue, just need the view to get updated automatically, once the 2nd activity closes. thx again for your explanation.

Comment: What you could do is save that text into the shared prefernces again before the activity closes in `onPause()`.
Then when it goes back to the previous activity it can get from the shared preferences as it did the first time

Answer (score 0):

Something that solved part of this problem for me was setting the receiving String variables to `null` like this:

```
public String param1new = null;
public String param2new= null;
```

My issue with this is I'm trying to set background colors on several `TextViews` and only the first one is being set at this time.